# Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting the following error:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
at listen (net.js:1064:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
at Function.app.listen     (C:\Users\mississauga\OneDrive\workspace\Editor\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:533:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mississauga\OneDrive\workspace\Editor\bin\www:7:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I have tried changing the port from 3000 to 8000, still got the same error. I closed the program and restarted my laptop, then tried running the program and I still get the same error. I used this [tutorial](https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-mongo). My code is very similar to the tutorial. My program was working fine but when I used socket.io I got an error, I removed the socket.io codes, and replaced them with my old working codes, except now my old codes are not working.

Here is my code.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter');
GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google');
FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook');
var routes = require('./routes');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var users = require('./routes/user');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();
var User = require('./Models/users.js')

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(flash());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
secret:'Cortana',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://blanksiadmin:Db6263779294@ds062097.mongolab.com:62097/users');
var conn = mongoose.connection;

var initPassport = require('./passport/init');
initPassport(passport);

var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
app.use('/', routes);

//mongoose.set('debug', true);
/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
err.message;
next(err);
});


// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
};


 // production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
});
});
conn.once('open', function(){
  console.log("connection Open");
})



module.exports = app;
```

www:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('my-application');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: The error isn't isolated to your code. `EADDRINUSE` means that there is another process on your computer that's already listening on the port you're trying to use here. You'll need to either find and kill the other process or listen on an unused port.

Comment: SOLVED: just use cmd as admin.